# want to echo a string in the price.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, price, if

I want to echo a string in my price.html  and im using this if statement

```
        <?php if($_product->getData('bogof')==1){
            echo 'test';} ?>
```

but it doesn't print anything i know the IF statement works as i use it in other places on my website. This is the context i am trying to use it in.

```
<?php $this->setProduct(
    Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton("catalog/config")->getProductAttributes())
        ->addAttributeToFilter("entity_id", $this->getProduct()->getId())
        ->setPage(1, 1)
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->load()
        ->getFirstItem()
);?>
<?php
$_coreHelper = $this->helper('core');
$_weeeHelper = $this->helper('weee');
$_taxHelper = $this->helper('tax');
/* @var $_coreHelper Mage_Core_Helper_Data */
/* @var $_weeeHelper Mage_Weee_Helper_Data */
/* @var $_taxHelper Mage_Tax_Helper_Data */


$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_storeId = $_product->getStoreId();
$_store = $_product->getStore();
$_id = $_product->getId();
$_weeeSeparator = '';
$_simplePricesTax = ($_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() || $_taxHelper->displayBothPrices());
$_minimalPriceValue = $_product->getMinimalPrice();
$_minimalPriceValue = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_minimalPriceValue));
 $_minimalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue);
$_convertedFinalPrice = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_product->getFinalPrice()));
$_specialPriceStoreLabel = $this->getProductAttribute('special_price')->getStoreLabel();
?>
<span class="price-excluding-tax" >

                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php if ($_finalPrice == $_price): ?>
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price, false) ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    </span>  
                <?php if($_product->getData('bogof')==1){
                    echo 'test';} ?>

                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. VAT') ?></span>
                </span>
```

Basically if the product has an attribute bogof and it is set to treu then it needs to print out test. But it isnt working and i am not sure why as it works in other files throughout my website.

When i add `$test = Mage::getSingleton("catalog/config")->getProductAttributes();`

then var_dump $test it returns

```
array(31) { [0]=> string(4) "name" [1]=> string(5) "price" [2]=> string(11) "small_image" [3]=> string(6) "status" [4]=> string(12) "tax_class_id" [5]=> string(7) "url_key" [6]=> string(9) "thumbnail" [7]=> string(17) "short_description" [8]=> string(13) "special_price" [9]=> string(17) "special_from_date" [10]=> string(15) "special_to_date" [11]=> string(14) "news_from_date" [12]=> string(12) "news_to_date" [13]=> string(16) "required_options" [14]=> string(10) "price_type" [15]=> string(11) "weight_type" [16]=> string(10) "price_view" [17]=> string(13) "shipment_type" [18]=> string(11) "image_label" [19]=> string(17) "small_image_label" [20]=> string(15) "thumbnail_label" [21]=> string(26) "links_purchased_separately" [22]=> string(11) "links_exist" [23]=> string(11) "is_imported" [24]=> string(12) "msrp_enabled" [25]=> string(30) "msrp_display_actual_price_type" [26]=> string(4) "msrp" [27]=> string(21) "c2c_paper_roll_holder" [28]=> string(10) "short_name" [29]=> string(15) "c2c_foot_switch" [30]=> string(9) "split_leg" }
```

And i have been told i need to add the bogog attribute to this array but i dont know how to that?

Comment: How is the product being loaded?  Part of a collection?

Comment: $_product = $this->getProduct();

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Try `echo $_product->getData('bogof')` at the top of price.phtml

Comment: i get this error 
Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in /home/theme/public_html/app/design/frontend/ourtheme/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml on line 35

Comment: Depending on the way the product is loaded, that attribute may not have the attribute data.  If iterating through a product collection it may well not, but if loading the product individually it always should.

Comment: (Am fairly new to this so this may all be wrong) But the product is ebign loaded in the view.phtml and just calling on the price.phtml to show the price. in the view.

Comment: Try reloading the product as a test and see if the data exists then. `$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());` and then pull the attribute data with `$_product->getBogof();`

Comment: what in the price.html ?

Comment: @jonathanHussey i have added code to my question where i believe it is loading the product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the call to the `addAttributeToSelect()` method against the product collection is adding your attribute.

```
->addAttributeToSelect('some_attribute', 'bogof')
```

or even just use `*` to select all attributes (although you may not want to do this in practice dependant on the number of attributes you have):

```
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
```

I would suggest looking at what is returned from `Mage::getSingleton("catalog/config")->getProductAttributes()` to make sure `bogof` isn't already included and if it isn't you can likely just add it in.  This will make the attribute data available to the product loaded from the collection.

Comment: When i add in $test = Mage::getSingleton("catalog/config")->getProductAttributes(). Then print test it just says array

Comment: Sorry what i just posted saying i got it working was a lie lol it was just print BOGOF on all products without a special price

Comment: You would be much better off inspecting the object with an IDE and xdebug, failing that `print_r` or `var_dump`.

Comment: i var_dump $test = Mage::getSingleton("catalog/config")->getProductAttributes() and it came back with the array but no bogof attribute in there

Comment: Ok well in that case edit the result of that method call to add your attribute in.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: You need me to explain how to add an item into an array?

Comment: i know how to add something to an array just dont know where to find the array to add it.

Comment: Ok well  I'm only going by what you said that the result of `Mage::getSingleton("catalog/config")->getProductAttributes()` is an array so you need to add your attribute into that array in the same format.

Comment: I have done it by using your original method $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); and then pull the attribute data with $_product->getBogof();

I think the first time i was putting it in the wrong place. Sorry about all the confusion and thank you for your patience !!

Comment: Great, glad it's working for you now.